# Metodo para convertir un String que contiene un numero en forma de letra, a int, ejemplo: "cuatro" -> 4 en java

Tags: java

Hay alguna clase que al pasarle por ejemplo un String "dos", me devuelva un int 2 por ejemplo?
El problema es que tengo numeros en formato de String, es decir "cuatro","tres","dos", etc., quiero convertirlos a su respectivo int, existe algun metodo que lo haga, hasta ahora lo que he hecho es algo como esto:

```
String numeroEnPalabra="cuatro";
    switch (numeroEnPalabra){
        case "uno":
            return 1;
        case "2":
            return 2;
        case "tres":
            return 3;
        case "cuatro":
            return 4;
         ...
        case "cien":
            return 100;
    }
```

Comment: Por favor revisa [ask] para que puedas formular una pregunta que sea aceptada por la comunidad. Muestra lo que has intentado o investigado.

Comment: gracias, he tratado de explicarla mejor

Answer (score 1):

A continuación te comparto un ejercicio que en su momento encontré en [Pasar de letras a numeros](http://www.forosdelweb.com/f45/pasar-letras-numeros-740182/). Revisa el link, si tienes dudas, puedes dejar un comentario.

```
public class Ejemplo{

    String[] Letras = { "UNO", "DOS", "TRES", "CUATRO", "CINCO", "SEIS",
            "SIETE", "OCHO", "NUEVE", "DIEZ", "ONCE", "DOCE", "TRECE",
            "CATORCE", "QUINCE", "DIECISEIS", "DIECISIETE", "DIECIOCHO",
            "DIECINUEVE", "VEINTE", "TREINTA", "CUARENTA", "CINCUENTA",
            "SESENTA", "SETENTA", "OCHENTA", "NOVENTA", "CIEN", "CIENTO",
            "DOSCIENTOS", "TRESCIENTOS", "CUATROCIENTOS", "QUINIENTOS",
            "SEISCIENTOS", "SETECIENTOS", "OCHOCIENTOS", "NOVECIENTOS" };

    Integer[] Valores = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
            17, 18, 19, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 100, 200, 300, 400,
            500, 600, 700, 800, 900 };

    List lstLetras = java.util.Arrays.asList(Letras);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Ejemplo().Letras();
    }

    public void Letras() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String palabra = null;
        System.out.println("Introduzca el numero: ");
        palabra = sc.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(palabra.toUpperCase());
        Integer numero = 0;

        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String t = st.nextToken();
            if (t.equals("MIL")) {
                numero *= 1000;
            }
            if (lstLetras.indexOf(t) > -1) {
                numero += Valores[lstLetras.indexOf(t)];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Resultado : " + String.valueOf(numero));
    }
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, me ha servido